# Pop up window closed without completion of the function

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I made a pop-up window that has a submit form and upon submission it must close but i first want to process the information from the pop-up window in a different page without displaying that other page. How can I do it?

my popupwindow contains this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"   
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function closeSelf(){
                self.close();
                return true;
            }
        </script>
        <title>Add Activity</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="./addact.php" method="post" onsubmit ="return closeSelf()">
        <table width="500" border="1"><br/>
            <tr>
                <td>Activity Name</td>
                <td>Assigned Person</td>
                <td>Deadline</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> <input name="activities" type="text" size="40%"/></td>
                <td><input name="name" type="text" size="40%"/></td>
                <td><input type="date" name="deadline" size="20%"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <input type="submit" name = "saved" id="saved"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

and my other page contains this

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>

    <?php
        include('config.php');

        $actname= $_POST['activities'];
        $assigned = $_POST['name'];
        $deadline = $_POST ['deadline'];

        $sql = "INSERT INTO ".$_SESSION['pname']."_activities 
                (actname, assigned, deadline) 
            VALUES 
                ('$actname', '$assigned', '$deadline')
        ";
        $query = mysql_query($sql);

        echo $_SESSION['pname'];

    ?>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: stop working on this and go read up about [sql injection attacks]](http://bobby-tables.com) before you go any farther. you're just begging to get your server pwn3d.

Comment: You should look into AJAX form submissions. And bind an `onclick` of submit button or `onsubmit` event to close the popup.

Comment: @Marc B thanks for the warning. I'l read up on securing my codes. I have no idea where to start. lol! but thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

You should close the window when the response is returned, not when you submit the page. And as @Marc B pointed out, you have major security problem!